# How to fix matplotlib's subplots when the entire layout can not be filled?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a DataFrame with say 29 columns, so I use the matplotlib's "subplots" command using 5x6 layout, (5x6 = 30 > 29)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,6)
```

However, when I plot all of the columns, the last subplot (i.e., row=5, col=6) is empty because there is no data to show there. Is there a way to remove that last subplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
fig.delaxes(axs[5,6]) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works for deleting the axes, however if I use sharex = True, xticks will be deleted as well. Is there is a way to move the xticks to the previous row?

Comment: if this is not the solution, whu you accept it? @motam79

Comment: I would use use axes[5, 6].axis('off'), for ticks, ax.set_xticks([]) should work.